# What does %F mean and how can I stop it meaning it?

Tags: zsh, rxvt

On an rxvt-clone (I'm using `rxvt-unicode` but it seems to happen on plain, old `rxvt` as well), the sequence of characters `%F` seems to have some sort of special meaning (as do a few others, such as `%S`).  In particular, I get the following:

```
% date +%F          
38;5;0m2011-04-02
% date +%F--%H.%M.%S
38;5;0m--.Hostname.2011-04-02--22.25.59
```

with the text after the `m` being in some dark almost-black colour.  Due to my colour scheme (mauve text on a dark blue polka dot background), this is almost unreadable.

What is this, and more importantly, how do I get it to stop?

To show why it is particularly annoying, my lecture documents have the date as part of their name.  It is therefore quite convenient to be able to write:

```
xelatex lecture.beamer.$(date +%F).tex
```

since I can store that in my history and recall it with a few judicious TABs.  However, the ensuing output is all the inverse of a whiter shade of pale, making it hard to see if there's an error.

In case it makes a difference, my shell is `zsh`.

Comment: Wasn't sure what to tag this, please retag as appropriate.

Comment: Best question title ever.

Comment: what is your shell? (not reproducing this with urxvt-unicode)

Comment: @Mat: As I say, my shell is zsh (4.3.10), and it happens with rxvt-unicode (9.07) (I also see now that I should withdraw my claim that it happens with rxvt since on my system, rxvt is a symlink to urxvt).

Comment: ah sorry missed that. anything suspicious in your `.zshrc`?

Comment: @Mat: Yes!!!  I found a line `preexec () { print -Pn "\e]0;%~: $2\a" }` (modulo a few conditionals).  Removing that removes the problem.  Unfortunately, I can't remember why I put that there!

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: That looks like it's trying to set the xterm window title to the command you executed, prefixed with the current directory.

Comment: @Mat: Thanks for the detective work.  In case it's not clear, until you suggested looking at `.zshrc`, I didn't even consider that it could be the culprit.  (Even then, I still wouldn't have known what to do about it!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In one of your comments, you mentioned using `zsh` with a `preexec` function that calls `print -P $2`.

In `zsh`, `print -P` accepts these format characters:

- `%F` means set the foreground color
- `%S` means set the standout attribute

See [zsh prompt expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#SEC52) for the full list.

So it's probably best to remove the `-P` flag from your call to `print` in `preexec`.

One way to get the same effect:

```
settitle() {
    printf "%b%s%b" "\033]0;" "$1" "\007"
}

tildedir() {
    print -Pn "%~" 
}

preexec() {
    settitle "$(tildedir):$2"
}
```

Comment: This looks great, thanks.  I'll test it tomorrow to be sure that it works.  (Now that I see your explanation of what that preexec does, I remember why I put it in and realise that I do want to keep it, so I'm particularly appreciative of this answer as it lets me do that!)

Comment: This works.  Thanks for solving the problem.